# we lost out on a big special next spring

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

What does "we lost out on a big special next spring" mean in context and why past tense of 'lost out' uses with 'next spring' in one sentense?

> "Meeting someone, Jimmy?" "No. Going to Miami for a conference. A
> heavy client. Bills six million. I'm supposed to hold his hand because
> we lost out on a big special next spring."

Stephen King
Quitters, Inc.

Comment: Why does it sound like an error to me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We would need even more context to be sure, this is a strange sentence.

But likely a business deal went wrong.  It involves both past and future tense because the events that ruined the deal have already happened, but the results of the deal would have been in the future (next spring).

Comment: I understand, most likely the meaning is like this, but what about grammar?

Comment: If you are asking if it is a correctly formed sentence, it is.  If you are asking for the grammatical names of the various parts, I'm sorry I do not have that answer.

Comment: Oh it's okay I'm satisfied.